# user data from user models with foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am new to django and trying a project to authenticate user using token and then user can post a *msg* on server in response user get *msg* he created and also has `user_id`, `username` and `email`.

This is a sample of what I want:

```
{

    "id": 102,
    "message": "Lorem ipsum",
    "created_at": "created time in UTC",
    "updated_at": "last updated time in UTC",
    "created_by": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "username": "testuser",
                    "email": "test@mail.com",
                    ...
    }
}
```

This is what I get:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "msg": "hello",
    "created_at": "2022-05-23T08:08:57.758428Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-05-23T08:08:57.758428Z",
    "created_by": null
}
```

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings

class MsgModel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    msg = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='username', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.msg
```

**serializers.py**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import MsgModel

class MsgSer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MsgModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include foreign table using serializers like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class MsgSer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by = UserSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MsgModel
        fields = ['id', 'msg', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'created_by']
```

Comment: Try your solution and now it's didn't show created_by response

Comment: I updated my answer. Include many=True in MsgSer class UserSerializer method. @ShivBagdi

Comment: Still not working